# Regexp: lazy, but not lazy enough

Tags: regex

I hope there are some regexp experts that can help. I have been searching for hours but can not find an answer.

This is the input string:

```
parameters:x,y,123,z;parameters:a,b,456,c;
```

The puzzle is to retreive the last parameters part (a,b,456,c) and I know it starts with "parameters:" and ends with ",c";

So I tried the following regexp:

```
parameters:(.+?,c);
```

This matches not the expected last part but the starting from the first parameters. This is the match group:

```
x,y,123,z;parameters:a,b,456,c
```

So the ? for doing a lazy match is not lazy enough as it matches more then I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not splitting by semicolon `;`, then match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to forbid `:` and `;` from matching:

```
parameters:([^:;]+,c);
```

Or you can be more explicit and forbid `parameters` from matching twice:

```
parameters:((?:(?!parameters).)+,c);
```

The reason why your regex wasn't lazy enough is that the regex match starts at the earliest possible position, and  `.+?` matches as much as necessary (which, from the first `parameters:` in the string, is exactly the string you found it to match).

Comment: Never thought of using a forbid construction. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The regex is exactly doing what you have defined: It matches "parameters" and then lazy till the first "c" it finds.

Try this:

```
parameters:([^;]+,c);
```

`[^;]` is a negated character class, that matches every character but ";". It seems that ; can not occur within such a group.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33vea)